# How to setup Steam VR Controller models and behavior in Unreal Engine?

Tags: models, unreal-4, unreal, htc-vive, blueprints

I want to preface this question by stating I am somewhat new to Unreal Engine. I googled for a solution to this, but no avail.

So I am setting up a bit of a sand box project in Unreal Engine to get a feel for VR development using the HTC Vive. The first thing I wanted to do was emulate the behavior of the motion controllers in the default Vive Screen. Basically, a 1:1 model of the controller appears inside the game space. It moves with the controller as you spin, point, twist and move the controller in real time. All the buttons respond in game when they are pressed in real life.

The solution I have hit on is to grab the raw model asset from /SteamApps/common/SteamVR/renderresource/ and manually line it up with the model ( by default the model is tiny, oriented wrong, and offset from the controller), and build individual events for each of the button that manipulates the models of the buttons in game. This seems kinda clunky and I was curious if there was a better way of doing this.